# Ignore multiple files in VC mode

Tags: vc

In VC Directory Mode, how do I ignore multiple files?

My use case is that I have a LaTeX repository (in SVN, but that should not matter) with over 15 `*.aux` files in a subdirectory.

#### Attempt 1

Mark a couple of files in VC Directory Mode, then run `C-x v G` (`vc-ignore`).  The command still asks me for a file, so it does not use the marks.

#### Attempt 2

Run `C-x v G` (`vc-ignore`) and fill in a Wildcard, e.g., `sections/*.aux`.  This does not exclude any files from the VC Directory Mode buffer (refreshed with `g`), but it does add the wildcard to SVN.  I.e., when I do `svn propedit svn:ignore .` then a buffer opens with the `sections/*.aux` line in there.

Comment: You could just give it a globbed file name (as you've written, i.e. `*.aux`). Or if you only want some specific files, then, I'm guessing that `C-x v d` would list the version-controlled directory the same way Dired would, then you could mark and operate on multiple files.

Comment: @wvxvw I'm able to make file in VC Directory mode, but `vc-ignore` does not act on them.  I'm adding the fact that I also tried that option to my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, for some reason `vc-dir-ignore` operates only on a single file. But this should be easy to remedy:

```lisp
(defun my/vc-ignore-multiple-files ()
  (interactive)
  (mapcar 'vc-ignore (vc-dir-marked-files)))

(define-key vc-dir-mode-map "a" 'my/vc-ignore-multiple-files)
```

Now marking several files and then pressing <kbd>a</kbd> will ignore all of them.